# BeautifulSoup for loop - combine results of every two loops

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse HTML using `beautifulSoup` that has the following structure:

```
   <table>
       <tr><td class="title">Title 2</td></tr>
   </table>
   <table>
       <tr><td>Label 1</td><td>Label 2</td><td>Label 3</td></tr>
       <tr><td class="data">Data 1</td><td class="data">Data 2</td><td class="data">Data33</td></tr>       </table>

   <table>
       <tr><td class="title">Title 2</td></tr>
   </table>
   <table>
       <tr><td>Label 1</td><td>Label 2</td><td>Label 3</td></tr>
       <tr><td class="data">Data 1</td><td class="data">Data 2</td><td class="data">Data33</td></tr>
   </table>
```

The issue I have is that I would like to add the title to the same row of a data frame as the data. But using a for loop (based on finding tables) I do not know how to get the title into the same list as the data points - so that the data to go into the data-frame would be [`title, Data 1, Data 2, Data 3`]

The python code is:

```
tables = soup.find_all('table')
i = 0
for t in tables:
    if(i % 2) == 1:
        datapoints = t.find_all('td', class_='data')
        data = []
        for d in datapoints:
            data.append(d.text)
        i += 1
    else:
        title = t.find('td', class_='title').text
        i += 1
```

I have tried wrapping it in another for loop, but that doesn't work because of the need to loop through the tables.

I could create two data-frames (one for titles, one for data) and then merge them at the end, but I would be surprised if that is the best way to do it.

Does anyone know how I can merge the results of sets of two for loops (i.e. `loop n and n+1`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using a `try..except`:

```
for table in soup.find_all('table'):
    try:
        title = table.find('td', class_='title').text
    except AttributeError:    # Triggers if no title present
        data = [td.text for td in table.find_all('td', class_='data')]
```

As to getting the list you want:

```
data = []
for table in soup.find_all('table'):
    try:
        data.append([table.find('td', class_='title').text])
    except AttributeError:    # Triggers if no title present
        data[-1].extend(td.text for td in table.find_all('td', class_='data'))
print(data)
# [['Title 1', 'Data 1', 'Data 2', 'Data33'],
#  ['Title 2', 'Data 1', 'Data 2', 'Data33']]
```

This works as long as the title is always immediately followed by the table with the corresponding data.

However, if you want to add it to a `pandas.DataFrame` afterwards, this is probably easier:

```
import pandas as pd

titles, data = [], []
for table in soup.find_all('table'):
    try:
        titles.append(table.find('td', class_='title').text)
    except AttributeError:    # Triggers if no title present
        data.append([td.text for td in table.find_all('td', class_='data')])
df = pd.DataFrame(zip(*data), columns=titles)
# df = pd.DataFrame.from_items(zip(titles, data))  # also works
print(df)
#   Title 1 Title 2
# 0  Data 1  Data 1
# 1  Data 2  Data 2
# 2  Data33  Data33
```

Comment: Thanks - yes a typo, have edited it. Would this not lead to the same issue, where the data I would like to combine is generated by different loops?

Comment: @HG123 If this solved your problem, you can accept an answer as the "correct" answer by clicking the check-mark on th left of it. Once you have earned enough reputation (15, which you will actually have after accepting an answer), you can also up-vote answers you found useful.

Comment: Thanks - have marked as correct - didn't realise I could do that sorry. Still says I don't have enough reputation but will upvote when I can

Answer (score 0):

Some comments:

- For better readability you could use `enumerate` in your main `for` loop
- If I don't misunderstood you, you already considered to use a dictionary but you do prefer to use 2D-arrays.
- You could use `zip()` for merging

  ```
  titles = [t.find('td', class_='title').text for idx,t in enumerate(tables) if idx % 2 == 0]

  datas = [[td.text for td in table.find_all('td', class_='data')] for idx,t in enumerate(tables) if idx % 2 != 0 ]

  structured = zip(titles,datas)
  ```